# Can't install Shopify-CLI on Window 11: Could not determine OS from platform x64-mingw-ucrt

Tags: ruby, shopify

I followed the instructions on the shopify website and everything seemed to install correctly...until I tried to confirm it with `shopify version`

Here's the cmd output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>gem install shopify-cli
Fetching shopify-cli-2.7.4.gem
Successfully installed shopify-cli-2.7.4
Parsing documentation for shopify-cli-2.7.4
Installing ri documentation for shopify-cli-2.7.4
Done installing documentation for shopify-cli after 3 seconds
1 gem installed

C:\WINDOWS\system32>shopify version
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui/os.rb:15:in `current': Could not determine OS from platform x64-mingw-ucrt (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui/spinner.rb:13:in `<module:Spinner>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui/spinner.rb:6:in `<module:UI>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui/spinner.rb:5:in `<module:CLI>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui/spinner.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/bin/shopify:9:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui.rb:19:in `<module:UI>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui.rb:2:in `<module:CLI>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/bin/shopify:9:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/lib/shopify_cli.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/bin/shopify:9:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/bin/load_shopify.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/bin/shopify:32:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/bin/shopify:32:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/shopify:25:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/shopify:25:in `<main>'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like a bug. You should report it [on their Github page](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/issues), but in the meantime you can fix it yourself:

In your editor open the file:

```
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.7.4/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui/os.rb
```

Find the line (around line 12) that says:

```
    when /mingw32/
      Windows
```

Change it to:

```
    when /mingw/
      Windows
```

And now try again.

Comment: fixed it for me, i installed 64bit maybe that cause it as it is 32 in that file?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in [version 2.10.2](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/releases/tag/v2.10.2).